# How to do a full-fledged search in the Outline view in Eclipse (CDT)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT for C code browsing at work.
Very often I like to search for a function name that I really don't know the name of.

The good part is that there is a search available and as soon as I start typing with my cursor in the Outline window, it starts looking for a match.

The problem, though, is that my guess has to match the beginning of the function name.

i.e. I can find get_var_xyz() by typing get_var_xyz() or narrow down to get_var_xyz and get_var_abc by typing get_var.

I cannot just simply search for xyz if I don't know what the preceding text is. That's what I want to be able to do.

Is there a setting for this hiding somewhere?
Or a plugin I could install?

Alternatively, it doesn't even have to be via Outline. As long as I can say "In the current file, show me all functions that contain this text"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

So I found this. If you do a "Ctrl+O" it brings up a small window called the quick outline. In this I can use wildcard (*) while searching which is extremely useful!

Comment: Thanks, i have same issue. Would be lovely if quick outline or even outline could be set with * as default and I could match from anywhere all the time so I don't have to type * constantly

Comment: I often use Ctrl+O, but it regularly crashes my Eclipse when i do this in big classes. Therefore i would prefer to have a filter/search function in the normal outline, since that one is a lot faster ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try Navigate->Open Element from the main menu. That dialog supports wildcards, has rich filtering capabilities and works across several files. If I need to find something in a single file, I usually use increamental find (Ctrl+J)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Eugene. I actually do use that option (Ctrl+Shift+G), but that is project/workspace wide search. I was looking for something in the Outline as that would be limited to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

For complex files, `"*"` crash in quick outline dialog. A workaround is type the  first, then navigate to the beginning and INSERT a `"*"`. It works for me, ugly :(